# IndexError: string index out of range. Только вот подскажите, пожалуйста, почему

Tags: python, индексы

```
x = 0
max = 0
count = 0
str = input()
for i in range(20):
    if int(str[i])==int(str[i+1])-1:
        count += 1
        if count > max:
            max = count
            i = x
    else:
        count = 0
print(x)
print(max)
```

Comment: Уточните пожалуйста, что вы хотите найти и покажите пример строки ввода.

Answer (score 1):

Очевидно, что у вас строка короче 20 символов, а код пытается читать символы с 0-го по 20-й, вот и выходит за пределы строки.

Надо так:

```
for i in range(len(str)-1):
```

PS: И ещё - не стоит использовать в качестве имён переменных слова max и str, это встроенные функции.